# How can water expand as it cools and freezes?

Tags: energy-conservation, water, freezing

It's well-known that water expands when it freezes to form ice, and perhaps less well-known to the common person that it actually begins expanding while still in liquid form when the temperature drops below 4 degrees C. This expansion must take some amount of energy, because it's capable of applying an immense amount of force, enough to crack rocks and so forth. My question is, if the water is cooling (i.e. giving off heat), where does it get the energy to perform this work?

I've read things like "it comes from the latent heat of fusion", but that doesn't really explain anything. I would expect a satisfactory answer to give me useful information about even just a handful of molecules.

My hypothesis would be that is has something to do with hydrogen bonds, like maybe as it cools, it forms hydrogen bonds, and the formation of those bonds releases energy. I don't know almost anything about hydrogen bonds, except that they are usually too small to matter for compounds other than water, so if I'm on the right track, I'd love to hear an intelligent explanation. Thanks.

Comment: Remember that as long as the water is *liquid* it cannot crack water pipes; any (small) expansion that occurs as the liquid water approaches the freezing point simply pushes back on the liquid water already in the pipe against the source pressure ("backflow"). pipe cracking occurs when the ice solidifies, because then there's no way to release the pent-up pressure via backflow.

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate, as they are subtly but substantively different. The linked question is essentially a question about applying the first law to the work done by freezing water: "where does the energy for doing work come from?" Whereas this question is essentially a question about the second law: "given the available energy, why does the system do work?"

Comment: There are a half dozen elements that have denser liquids than the solid at the melting point. Those clearly do not have hydrogen bonds as the reason.

Comment: @JonCuster can you explain what the reason is for any of them?